# Accordion slides under the header

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on an activated link within my accordion in slides under the header. I have tried everything I could think of. If you need more information please tell me in the comments below. Thank you in advance.

The following is all HTML

Header

```
<header>
    <img style="border-width: 0px;" src="Photo/Informatique.png" width="500" height="150" alt="Informatique" class="align-center"/>
    <section class="s2">
    <form action="http://www.example.org/subscribe.php">
    <p>Recherche:</p>
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Enter Keyword"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Recherche">
    </form>
    </section>
</header>
```

Accordion

```
<!-- BEGIN COMPONENT Accordion - Taco HTML Edit -->
    <div id="myAccordion" class="tswAccordion">
    <div class="tswAccordionInactiveSection">
    <div class="tswAccordionHeader">ACCUEIL</div>
    <div class="tswAccordionBody">

        <section class="s1">
        <p> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer molestie vehicula hendrerit. Aliquam venenatis quam orci, iaculis cursus enim molestie et. Nullam fringilla gravida eros, eu volutpat tellus elementum et. In vitae dignissim est. Quisque vitae metus lacinia, vulputate arcu eget, suscipit dolor. Integer scelerisque, lorem ut tempor consequat, arcu justo dictum elit, blandit adipiscing enim quam eget lorem. Curabitur nec nunc malesuada, lobortis massa id, fermentum leo.
        <p>
        </section>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Activated Links Within Accordion

```
<div class="tswTabContent">
<div class="tswTabContentSelected">
<img src=Photo/gimp.png width="100" height="100" alt="Gimp" style="float:right">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <h1>Débutant</h1>
        <nav class="Tutoriel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#5%20petits%20didacticiels">5 petits didacticiels</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Mettre%20en%20valeur">Mettre en valeur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Les%207%20erreurs">Les 7 erreurs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Paysage%20glacial">Paysage glacial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Effet%20Pop-Art">Effet Pop-Art</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>  
        </td>
```

Comment: I want someone to help me fix the problem. I want my accordion to stop sliding/moving. In other works fix it in place.

Comment: Put this in a http://jsfiddle.net with the given code. It is impossible to tell why it happens

Comment: @Huangism this is how it looks like in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYuKd/). The accordion is missing. Am I doing something wrong?